# Chiarimenti sui verbi “presupporre” e “richiedere”

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, difference

"È una situazione che richiede/presuppone la massima chiarezza".
"È una situazione che richiede/presuppone che ci sia la massima chiarezza".
I verbi presupporre e richiedere molto spesso vengono considerati sinonimi di "implicare/comportare" che sono verbi che esprimono una conseguenza ricavata da un'azione:
"La situazione comporta/implica la massima chiarezza".
Qui si parla di una conseguenza.
Per quanto invece riguarda i verbi presupporre e richiedere mi pare che esprimano una necessità ed è per questo che li vedo molto più vicini a verbi come necessitare.
Voi che dite?

Comment: Non capisco bene la domanda: stai chiedendo sulle sfumature di significato di questi verbi?

Comment: «I verbi presupporre e richiedere molto spesso vengono considerati sinonimi di "implicare/comportare"»: Dove hai letto una cosa del genere? Significano quasi il contrario.

Comment: Intanto, hai consultato un dizionario monolingue, cercato i verbi “presupporre”, “chiedere”, “implicare” e “comportare”, letto con attenzione le definizioni e gli esempi? Se sì, quali dubbi ti rimangono?

Answer (score 3):

L'etimologia latina del verbo *presupporre* è *prae*-*sub*-*ponere*. La seconda parte, *subponere* significa, letteralmente, *mettere sotto*, cioè “porre alla base”: una *supposizione* è una base del ragionamento successivo (non necessariamente vera). Con l'aggiunta di *prae*, diventa una supposizione che non facciamo noi, ma che ci viene da qualcun altro e sulla quale *dobbiamo* basare il ragionamento.

Il verbo *comportare* invece viene da *cum*-*portare* (il verbo è tardo latino): “portare insieme”. Dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/comportare)

> Portare con sé, richiedere come conseguenza: *il viaggio comporterà molte spese*; *la concessione delle attenuanti comporta una riduzione di pena*.

Dunque *presupporre* e *comportare* non sono sinonimi, anche se in certe situazioni possono sostituirsi l'uno con l'altro se non c'è un nesso di causalità certo fra due fenomeni, cioè non si sa quale dei due causi l'altro.

Completamente diverso è il caso di *richiedere* e *implicare*: *la situazione richiede la massima chiarezza* significa che dobbiamo prima chiarirci per bene e poi possiamo esaminare la situazione per trovare il modo di uscirne; al contrario, *la situazione implica la massima chiarezza* significa che questa situazione ha come effetto la massima chiarezza (anche se non lo direi mai). Sempre dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/implicare/)

> *la firma del contratto implica l’accettazione di tutte le sue clausole*; *le vostre parole implicano una contraddizione*

Una frase come *la firma del contratto richiede l’accettazione di tutte le sue clausole* significa che **prima** di firmare il contratto bisogna accettare le clausole; la frase con *implica* invece significa che la firma del contratto ha come conseguenza la tacita accettazione delle clausole.

Parlando da docente di matematica, trovo che spesso gli studenti non hanno chiaro il concetto di “implicazione” e spesso confondono l'antecedente con il conseguente.

Comment: Ottima risposta!